# How can I alert developers they need to run certain commands after they pull my commit (in version control/git)?

Tags: git, mercurial, development-environment, githooks, mercurial-hook

Here’s a common scenario:

You’re working on a project (such as, but not necessarily, a web app) with other developers.

1. I decide we should use a certain open-sourced tool and add it to the project dependencies. Of course, I add it to our package manager, which is in source control. *or*
2. Tom realizes we can speed up our database queries by adding an index and denormalizing a bit of data. He adds a migration and checks it in.

In either scenario, when other developers `git pull` or otherwise update their development environment, things are likely to break unless they run `npm install` / `bundle` / `cocoapods chocolateygoodness` / `bower feathernest` or `python manage.py migrate` / `bundle exec rake migrate` or whatever, and it’s *not always obvious*  that this is the case. In fact, the other developer might not *really* be a developer at all, but perhaps a designer who is beautifying the cheezus out of our UI.

What I would ***really like*** is for every other developer, upon `pull`ing the commit in question, to see something like this:

```
Updated! 

Please note you MUST RUN this command before continuing. 
(Stop your server first, if applicable)

$ ./magical_command_here --with-args
```

Alternatively, it would be amazing if running `git status` could output something like:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Migrations need to be run. Please execute `database_migration_command`
```

Who has solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is really not VCS's concern.  This should be managed at build.  The solutions is to include, as part of the source, a build script which takes care of this.  If you add a dependency that is not already being taken care of by the build script, then update the build script and include it in the commit.  Collaborators should know to run the build script as part of the development cycle.

Comment: I don't agree that this is the only approach. Git has the ability to add hooks to allow for this kind of reminder. Using Git's post-merge hook, additional checks similar to the ones in version control / build scripts can be run to alert the user or run commands for them.

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward to solve with the use of Git hooks. I’m not sure about other VCS software but here is [the documentation for the `post-merge` hook found it Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge).

A simple example of how to use this check for things is to leverage the following Bash commands inside of that script to compare the current state of HEAD with the previous state of HEAD in your Git repository after the pull occurs.

You can use `git` and `grep` to achieve this within the post-merge hook script.

```
git diff --name-only 'HEAD@{1}' HEAD | grep "^$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Here’s [a link to a working script with comments](https://gist.github.com/rogeruiz/1f523b878ca741b194e7f5c224310fb2) that you can copy into your project to use with the Git post-merge hook.